# Loop runs ad infinitum, regardless of int entered

Tags: do-while, cs50, cc

I've take a break since I posted this and have read through half of the C programming book I'm studying (Harvard cs50 book). I should be able to solve this by now, yet am unable.

The program runs in a continuous loop, no matter what integer is entered; prints "Good for you..." ad infinitum.

Example code:

```
//example 3 version2 from chapter 11, beginner programming in c
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main ()
{

        int prefer;

        printf("On a scale from 1 to 10, how happy are you?\n");
        scanf(" %d", &prefer);

        while(prefer >= 1  || prefer <= 10)
                //goal is for program to run while entered int "prefer" is between 1 - 10
                if (prefer > 10)
                {
                        printf("Oh really, now?  Can't follow simple directions, can you?\n");
                        printf("want to try that again?  1 through 10...?\n");
                        scanf(" %d", &prefer);
                }
                else if (prefer >= 8)
                {
                        printf("Good for you!\n");
                }
                else if (prefer <= 5)
                {
                        printf("Cheer up : )\n");
                }
                else if (prefer <= 3)
                {
                        printf("Cheer up, Buttercup!\n");
                }
                else
                {
                        printf("Get in the RIVER with that attitude!\n");
                }
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: There are quite a few problems with this code. In particular this makes little sense `while(prefer >= 10 && < 0);`  The syntax is wrong.

Comment: Also how many numbers do you know that can be `>= 10 AND < 0`?  Consider carefully what you need.

Comment: Whatever makes you think the "and" operating in C and the "and" word in English have all of the same meanings, lose it... get yourself a decent book, instead. Alternatively, consider a different programming language, though you'll probably have the same problem with those. Consider that "and" means multiple things in English. In programming, typically, only one of those meanings applies. You've chosen the wrong definition, that is all.

Comment: Actually, I didn't mean to use "and" at all, but "or."  Thanks.  I do appreciate the help.  I am following a book actually.  Apparently, not well... : /

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to this.  Understood.  Edited per your suggestion.  Please let me know if anything is amiss.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Operator `<` and `&&` are binary operators. When we use them, it compares the left and right side values. The above while would look like this.

```
while(prefer <= 10 && prefer > 0);
```

Comment: The key is that the `&&` operator determines if both of two things are true, the thing on the left and the thing on the right. On the right is `< 0`, which is not a thing that can be true, it's part of a comparison.